# Sum the product of two columns in Google Spreadsheets

Tags: google-sheets

Here's the situation:

```
ITEM COST CUST1  CUST2  CUST3    TQTY

foo  $0.5     1      0    0.5     1.5
baz  $1.0     2      1      0       3
bar  $1.5   0.5      0    0.3     0.8

SUBT       $2.75 $1.00  $0.75   $4.50
```

Simple, right? The `SUBT` row should have the contents of

```
CUST1*COST, CUST2*COST, CUST3*COST
```

for each row. And the `TQTY` column has the sum of

```
CUST1+CUST2+CUST3
```

for each row.

At least it SHOULD be simple, but auto-fill keeps screwing me. `TQTY` is easy, of course, but I can't for the life of me figure out how to use a formula to give me the sum of the product of two columns cell by cell.  In particular, I need to do this in a way that will be user-manageable for someone wanting to insert rows or columns in the middle and have it continue to "just work".

Comment: Hi Jim, can't reproduce your figures. Shouldn't you be using `SUMPRODUCT` for `COST` and `CUST1` to have the total per customer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will sum the quantities, per row, for all rows in the range.

### Formula

```
 =ARRAYFORMULA(SUMIF(IF(COLUMN(C2:E4),ROW(C2:E4)),ROW(C2:E4),C2:E4))
```

### Screenshot

[image]

### Example

I've created an example file for you: **[Sum over rows](https://docs.google.com/a/jacobjantuinstra.nl/spreadsheets/d/1ox_diuk2s1tV6Lh98QijXzn0yrBSs5vsdjSzdqaNTxc/edit?usp=sharing)**

### Reference

https://stackoverflow.com/a/21804838/1536038

Comment: Thank you so much - SUMPRODUCT is exactly what I was looking for (TQTY wasn't the sticking part, I can get that just by summing b2:e2, etc).

Answer (score 1):

The right function to use is **SumProduct**

**Formula**

```
=SUMPRODUCT(array1, [array2, ...])
```

**Screenshot**

[image: Screenshot of using SUMPRODUCT function]